# Best way to query for most recent based on datetime (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

If i had a table that stored a person's name, the time it took them to run a mile, and when they ran said mile, what would be the best way to get a person most recent lap-time.

```
LAPS
____________________________________________
|  name   | lap_time |        date         |
--------------------------------------------
| George  |   20.3   | 2013-01-17 09:17:14 |
| Alex    |   32.2   | 2013-02-17 14:24:32 |         
| Mike    |   16.6   | 2013-01-17 07:57:54 |
| Alex    |   28.5   | 2013-01-17 19:50:21 |
| Mike    |   15.1   | 2013-02-17 12:37:12 |
| Mike    |   14.8   | 2013-03-17 06:58:34 |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

I've been doing it this way, and it has worked for me so far, but I'm curious to know if there is a better way.

```
SELECT l.lap_time
FROM laps l
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT *, MAX(date) as most_recent
    FROM laps
    WHERE name = 'Alex'
)AS temp ON (
    l.date = temp.most_recent
    AND l.name = temp.name
)
```

The actual table that i'm using this type of query on is huge, so i'm looking for the most time efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Why not just `ORDER BY date DESC`?

Comment: @jakerella Because OP is looking for the `MAX(date)`

Comment: @njk Well, he said "most recent lap-time", so why not just use `SELECT lap_time FROM laps WHERE name = 'Alex' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @jakerella You're right. Misread. Thought OP wanted all names.

Comment: @njk no worries... I just thought I was missing something!

Comment: @njk Thanks, I was unaware I could set a LIMIT, I'm very new to writing queries, sort of learning it on the go now out of necessity.

Comment: @Lex Appropriately indexed, and assuming you really want to return EVERYBODY's most recent lap time, my guess is that your way will be as fast as any other suggested so far (and very nearly as fast as any that might yet be suggested - but I'm only guessing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for a single name:

```
SELECT name, lap_time, date
FROM laps
WHERE name = 'Alex'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Result**

```
| NAME | LAP_TIME |                            DATE |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Alex |     32.2 | February, 17 2013 14:24:32+0000 |
```

### [See the demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a23eb/2)

This should work for all names:

```
SELECT a.name, b.lap_time, a.date
FROM
  (SELECT name, MAX(date) AS date FROM laps GROUP BY name) a
LEFT JOIN laps b 
  ON b.date = a.date AND b.name = a.name
```

**Result**

```
|   NAME | LAP_TIME |                            DATE |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   Alex |     32.2 | February, 17 2013 14:24:32+0000 |
| George |     20.3 |  January, 17 2013 09:17:14+0000 |
|   Mike |     14.8 |    March, 17 2013 06:58:34+0000 |
```

### [See the demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a23eb/1)

Answer (score 1):

I would test it with this query and with MAX to see which is faster.

```
Select * from laps where name = 'Alex' order by date desc limit 1;
```